# PHP: Retrieving JSON via jQuery ajax help

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Hey I have a script that is creating and echoing a JSON encoded array of magento products.

I have a script that calls this script using jQuery's ajax function but I'm not getting a proper response. When the GET request is performed firebug displays

```
GET http://localhost.com/magento/modules/products/get.php 200 OK then a **red cross** then 361ms
```

This is the script that creates the array:

```
 // Load product collection
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
 $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
 $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');

 $products = array();

 foreach ($collection as $product){
     $products[] = array("price" => $product->getPrice(),
                         "name" => $product->getName() );
 }

 header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
 echo(json_encode($products));
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost.com/magento/modules/products/get.php",
                    success: function(products)
                    {
                        $.each(products,function()
                        {
                            var opt = $('<option />');
                            opt.val(this.name);
                            opt.text(this.price);
                            $('#products').append(opt);
                        });
                    }
            });
        })
</script>
```

I'm getting a response from this but I'm not seeing a any JSON. I'm using firebug. I can see there has been a JSON encoded response but the response tab is emtyp and my select boxes have no options.

Can anyone see and problems with my code?

Here is the response I should get (and do get when I run the script manually via the browser):

```
[{"price":"82.9230","name":"Dummy"},{"price":"177.0098","name":"Dummy 2"},{"price":"76.0208","name":"Dummy 3"},{"price":"470.6054","name":"Dummy 4"},{"price":"357.0083","name":"Dummy Product 5"}]
```

Thanks,

Billy

Comment: What you recive when you just open http://localhost.com/magento/modules/products/get.php as page <

Comment: my scipt is returning JSON correctly. I run that script and get a JSON encoded array of products

Comment: your JSON may have errors. try copying get.php output and pasting it after `var a=` in firebug

Comment: I have added my JSON response when I open the script directly

Answer (score 0):

use `cache: false`, as one of your AJAX parameters...

I know when i used JSON in AJAX, i had to do this:

```
                    success: function(data) {
                      $(".custName, .projectDesc").empty();
                      for(var x in data) {
                         $(".custName").append(data[x].message1);
                         $(".projectDesc").append(data[x].message2);
                    }
```

I'm not sure if this will help you or not :)

Comment: Thanks but didn't make a difference :(

Answer (score 0):

The PHP you're returning is not an array of objects, which is the way you are treating it in your javascript.

Change your PHP to:

```
$products = array();
foreach( $collection as $product ) {
  $products[] = array( "price" => $product->getPrice(),
                       "name" => $product->getName() );
}
```

This should return JSON that looks like:

```
[{"price":"82.9230","name":"Dummy"},{"price":"177.0098","name":"Dummy 2"}, etc ]
```

jQuery.each should then be able to iterate over the returned array of objects:

```
success: function(products) 
{
  jQuery.each(products,function()
       {

       var opt = jQuery('<option />'); 
          opt.val(this.name);
          opt.text(this.price);
          jQuery('#products').append(opt); 
       });
  }
```

Comment: Since when do you have to parse JSON response when the request type is set to JSON? I've never done that and it worked...

Comment: Updated my answer based on JSON that was posted.

Comment: Hi I've updated my code based on your answer but still no luch. My GET request seems to be fine though

Comment: also I can't use $products[] = new array. I get an error unless I take out 'new' however my JSON is in the correct format

Comment: Sorry, my mistake on the new.  Mixing languages.  What does your result from your php script look like?

Comment: Hi Chris, [{"price":"82.9230","name":"Dummy"},{"price":"177.0098","name":"Dummy 2"},{"price":"76.0208","name":"Dummy 3"},{"price":"470.6054","name":"Dummy 4"},{"price":"357.0083","name":"Dummy Product 5"}]

Comment: That looks right, and works here: http://jsfiddle.net/hskbv/1/.  Note that the first three parameters of the $.ajax request will be different for you.  In my example they are required to get jsFiddle to simulate an ajax response.  Stick a breakpoint in your success function and make sure you're getting something that looks like an array of objects.

Comment: If I change my type to 'POST' it seems to not run. It's like it's just not firing the ajax request. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change to POST.  In the fiddle example, I had to use POST to get the simulated AJAX response to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(products,function(index, arr)
{
      var opt = $('<option />');
      opt.val(arr[name]);
      opt.text(arr[price]);
      $('#products').append(opt);
});
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: It's the response that's the problem, I'm getting the correct response when I access the controller directly but when the ajax request is run I get the proper headers returned but the response is empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to add data type property on $.ajax configuration object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost.com/magento/modules/products/get.php",
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(products) {
                $.each(products,function() {
                    var opt = $('<option />');
                    opt.val(this.name);
                    opt.text(this.price);
                    $('#products').append(opt);
                });
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Maybe, $.ajax function doesn't know the response data type...

Comment: unfortunately hasn't made a difference :(

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType: 'json'` in `jQuery.ajax` parameter